# Why is my page not redirecting after login?

Tags: php, redirect, header

I've looked through this about a hundred times and can't find a reason the page won't redirect.  I can't find any spaces or any output I might be missing.   Can anyone spot the problem?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include_once('includes/sessions.php');
include_once('connections/localhost.php');
include_once('includes/functions.php');
include_once('includes/validations.php');
?>
<?php
$username = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $required_fields = array("username", "password");
  validate_there($required_fields);
  if (empty($errors)) {
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $found_user = attempt_login($username, $password);
    if ($found_user) {
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $found_user["user_id"];
    $_SESSION["username"] = $found_user["username"];
    redirect_to("index.php");     
    } else {
      $_SESSION["message"] = "Username/password not found.";
    }
  }
} else {
} 
?>
```

Here is the function for redirecting:

```
function redirect_to($new_location) {
      header("Location: " . $new_location);
      exit;
    }
```

Here are the validation functions:

```
$errors = array();

function fieldname_is_text($fieldname) {
  $fieldname = str_replace("_", " ", $fieldname);
  $fieldname = ucfirst($fieldname);
  return $fieldname;
}


function has_presence($value) {
    return isset($value) && $value !== "";
}

function validate_there($required_fields) {
  global $errors;
  foreach($required_fields as $field) {
    $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
    if (!has_presence($value)) {
        $errors[$field] = fieldname_is_text($field) . " can't be blank";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Not that it should matter, but why are you closing and then reopening your PHP enclosures? (i.e. `?>
<?php`). Also, is the URL of your login page the same as the URL of your redirect page?

Comment: post your code for `$found_user` and `validate_there`

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. 
I put the ?> <?php to keep it clean visually (to me.)   I didn't think that would matter.  I've removed it and it hasn't fixed it.   The login page is login.php and I want to redirect to the index.php page.

Comment: I updated my code to show the validation functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have any output (HTML or error messages) before calling the header-function. All headers should be sent before you can send the output.

Some output you can't see, but is there. Such as spaces etc. Try removing the

```
?>
<?php
```

Comment: yeah but where?  I don't see any output or error messages when I turn them on.

Comment: @SherwoodPro `?>
<?php` here you have output of empty string

Comment: Also check your included files. If they are meant to contain only PHP it is safe to remove the ?> at the end of the file. This prevents any spaces afterwards from being sent to the browser. There are some discussions whether it is good coding practice to skip your closing tag, but is is valid PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try this function for redirection.

```
<?php
function redirect_to($new_location)
{
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = '<?php echo $new_location;?>';
</script>
<?php
}

?>
```

Comment: I couldnt' get this to work.  It just kept giving me a blank page.  Thanks though.  : )

Comment: Make you are passing value in function and variable have value ( page path), $new_location ...